# Como filtrar valores por palavra chave no array?

Tags: php, array, arraylist

Os códigos abaixo não estão funcionando muito bem do jeito que eu quero:

```
$array = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June');

function filterDataByValue(array $array, $value)
    {
        $filtered = array_filter($array, function ($var) use ($value) {
            return ($var !== $value);
        });

        return $filtered;
    }

   function filterDataByValues(array $array, array $values)
    {
        $filtered = array();
        if (count($values)) {
            foreach ($values as $k => $val) {
               $filtered[$k] = array_values(filterDataByValue($array, $val));

            }
        }
        return $filtered;
    }

    $data = array_values(filterDataByValues($array, array('January','April')));



    print_r($data);
```

Gostaria de filtrar uma lista de valores e remover do meu array.
Obs, mas não pela chave, pela palavra. Exemplo:

tenho um array:

```
$frutas_origem = array('Pêssego', 'Maçã', 'Abacaxi', 'Morango');
```

Remover as palavras Maçã e Morango:

```
$frutas_remocao = array('Maçã', 'Morango');
```

Tenho o resultado:

```
$frutas_resultado = array('Pêssego', 'Abacaxi');
```

O primeiro método que publiquei remove o valor, mas o que eu quero é passar uma lista e remover os itens, exemplo:

```
$frutas_resultado = metodoRemover($frutas_origem, $frutas_remocao);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui usando array_diff():

```
function filterDataByValues(array $array, array $values)
{
     $filtered = array_diff($array, $values);
     return $filtered;
}
```